# MS Access Query Loop Macro

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, vba

I am trying to code an exe in MS Access that contains a loop of queries.
The exe will take a csv file and loop through lines of code running multiple queries to execute different functions.

The loops are shown below in an image:

[image: Query Loops]

The queries already exist, can they be simply called into a loop similar to php variables?

Furthermore, can I set a variable that will carry through future queries as they are to be run in a particular looped order? (Such that the variable `min_value` is set in the first query and carried into the second query and third and so forth...

--------- Added at 1393846838 as requested by @ElectricLlama ---------

Queries are as follows:

set $time query

```
SELECT datediff("s", #1/1/1970#, now()) AS unix_time;
```

select minimum value query

```
SELECT Min(Field4) AS min_value FROM Market;
```

select * where min query

```
SELECT * FROM Market WHERE Field4=min_value;
```

count (min) value query

```
SELECT count(Field4) AS count_total FROM Market WHERE field4=min_value;
```

The necessity for a loop is due to some variables in one query being either null or 1 and in another query either being 1 or >1

Thank-you

--------- Added at 1393855784 as requested by @ElectricLlama ---------

[image]

Comment: You can create a variable that will last the entire time Access is open (Global), or while a Form is open (form level, before first executable statement). I assume you are planning to run this process from a form? Yes, you can write one procedure (or function) that runs all of the logic you have drawn up.

Comment: That's corredct @WayneG.Dunn :) I will be running this from a form (exe is the wrong term). I am struggling to write said procedure or function to run this logic. Any guidance or direction that you can point me in please?

Comment: It's entirely likely that this can be achieved by combining a number of queries rather than performing any looping. If you want to proceed with the coding option at least post the code you have tried (i.e. `Sub MyFirstTry End Sub` If you would like to explore how this might be done with queries only, provide some sample data.

Comment: Hi @ElectricLlama, I haven't coded any macros but will edit my above post to include queries

Comment: To clarify, the looping thing will need to be done in VBA rather than an Access macro - are you familiar with VBA? It would also be helpful to post the structure of the CSV file.

Comment: Try creating this as ONE query: `SELECT market, min(Field4) as min_value FROM Market GROUP BY market` This gets you a single recordset that you can loop around. To take it a step further it gives you a query that you can join to another query and avoid loops altogether. If the purpose of `$time` is to get a unix timestamp to insert into a table, this can be done afterwards.

Comment: Hi @ElectricLlama I will post the csv in a second. I found that I needed to grab $time variable at one point so as it doesn't change (this is due to QuickBooks using the timestamp to distinguish between different invoices)

Comment: Perhaps you could take a step back and explain what you're trying to do? looking at your flowchart, if there is a unique Field4 value, you copy it into another table without generating $time and if it isn't unique you generate $time and insert then individually. Is this all just to generate a unique code for quickbooks? because if your macro runs faster than 1 second per loop, it is not going to be unique and there are FAR simpler ways of generating unique numbers, like for example copying your records into a table that has an autonumber field. Have you considered doing it that way?

Comment: You have not explained what you want to do with the rows returned by the `SELECT` queries.

Comment: I am trying to take a csv file that has a day worth of transaction from outside of the office environment (no access to QuickBooks) and import said data when in the office. The reason that I need to loop through the queries above is that some transactions have the same Field4 (transaction number) which dictates two (or more) line items on the same invoice number (which requires the same unix timestamp to do so). I need a very simple loop structure that I can adapt to place these queries into it

Comment: You do not need to use a loop or macros. You can use a single query to automatically generate line numbers when required. Are you familiar with MS Access queries? Where does UNIX come into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions because your flowchart doesn't correlate with your sample data, but.... here is a sample query that automatically builds your line number. But it requires your data to be first loaded into a table with an autonumber in it. This would be a two step process but without any loops or complexities in it. If you can get this to work it will be faster and easier to maintain and debug than a big chunk of nested loop VBA code. Not to mention that your `$time` variable will not be unique if your loop takes less than a second to run.

```
SELECT 
T1.ID, T1.Field1, T1.Field2, T1.Field3, T1.Field4, 
(    select count(*) 
     from Table1 T2 
     WHERE T2.Field3=T1.Field3 
     AND T2.ID < T1.ID
) AS LineNum
FROM Table1 AS T1;
```

This query generates an incrementing line number against any records with the same Field3

Comment: Hi @ElectricLlama, is there any way to loop through the queries without writing them directly into vb script?

Comment: If you run this query there is no looping at all. But addressing what I think is your question: Yes. You create MS Access queries, possibly with parameters. Then you use code inside VBA to refer the the 'querydefs', rather than the SELECT queries themselves. Again, your $time query will not solve your problem - it will produce duplicate line numbers if it takes less than a second to run.

Comment: I understand the time variable issue and duplicate line numbers don't seem to a problem thus far. It's more getting my head around the structure and design of vb code as opposed to php based coding (as I mainly use php in my work).

Comment: OK well I"ll just leave it at this - there is no VBA coding in my solution, nor is there any required. It's a set based solution. You might need a macro to tie together a few sequential SQL statements but there are no loops or coding.

Comment: Thank-you and Sorry for my poor understanding and thus tricky topic.

Comment: Thats fine... all I'm getting at is that you have posed a 'procedural' solution to something that would probably be better solved in a 'set based' manner.   If you are not comfortable pursuing the set based solution I can assist with the procedural solution also.